# Point load distribution inside elastic solid continuum medium in finite elements method

Tags: forces, computational-physics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

In finite elements method, when point load is applied to a particular node of elastic solid continuum medium (e.g. soil), does it affect nodal forces in the rest of the mesh (i.e. does each node experience a fraction of the applied load as a result of force distribution) or is it assumed that it only affects that one node while nothing else changes in the rest of the mesh (i.e. nodal forces stay the same)? In case force distribution is a thing, which law reflects it?

---

Example mesh (elastic solid continuum medium, e.g. soil):

[image]

Asking the question in terms of this example, does the fact that load is applied directly to the `red` node mean that the nodal forces of the `green` node are *somehow* changed too?

Comment: Concerning your edit:  The "homework-like question" close reason is for questions that ask "about specific computations instead of underlying physics concepts", which this one seems to.  A question doesn't have to be asked in a class to be a "homework question" on this site.  Also, FYI, it's not necessarily moderators who close questions; any user with enough rep can cast close (or re-open) votes on questions if they think it doesn't meet the guidelines, and a question is closed (or re-opened) if it gets enough votes.  I hope that helps explain why & how your question was closed. ...

Comment: ... So yes, I would try re-asking the problem in a one-sentence form, with a clearly defined concept underlying it.  (Your proposed formulation looks much better.) And then delete most of the rest, except for maybe a single example setup; it distracts from the underlying conceptual question. You can always ask the other parts as a separate follow-up question later on if you're still confused about them.

Comment: How about asking this question on [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @HEMMI Well, I don't ask about how to implement it, I'm asking strictly about physics - do forces get distributed ( and if yes then which law reflects it) or do they just stay in the nodes they are applied directly onto.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks for heads up. This is really silly that I try to illustrate my question so it boils down to simple samples and then someone doesn't like it and deletes it. I honestly don't think I want to waste more of my time on this forum; it went far worse than my expectations were.

Comment: is this a continuum medium or a truss structure?

Comment: @bigmazi, I'm voting for reopening. I'll give you an answer as soon as possible

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Anyways, as per your advice, I deleted almost everything, basically, and reformulated it in a couple of sentences.

Comment: @basics Continuum - soil to be exact. Thanks for a good question, I'm going to specify it.

Comment: I've also voted to re-open.

Comment: @bigmazi i guess I'll provide you an answer tomorrow. Meanwhile, I'd tell you that Finite Element Methods could be seen as a projection on a set of base functions, much better than as a physical law

Answer (score 1):

Solving elastic loaded solids by FEM results in an equation: $KX = F$, where $K$ is a square matrix depending on the type of elements, elastic parameters and dimensions, $X$ is a column matrix of the displacement of the nodes, and $F$ is a column matrix for the applied forces on the nodes. In your example, the vertical force in the red node is one element of $F$.

So, the solution of the problem is solving the resultant system of equations, and of course all other nodes (the $X$ column matrix) will have defined values as a consequence. The force on one node affects all of them.

Comment: So, both displacements and forces are treated as variables in the equations system? But wouldn't it have infinite amount of solutions? That's too many variables for a linear system, isn't it?

Comment: Like, in the example mesh from the question there are 45 nodes thus 45 Hooke's equations (for vertical displacement) but 45 unkown vertical forces and 45 - 9 = 36 unkown displacement (9 displacements in fixed nodes are known). One extra equation states that sum of vertical forces equals vertical load. So, 45 + 1 = 46 equations for 45 + 36 = 81 variables.

Comment: @bigmazi you have to know the loading pattern. Only the displacements are unknown. In the picture for example there is only one vertical force on one particular node. And some nodes with zero prescribed displacements. The others are supposed to have zero external force on them.

Comment: Okay, so the forces are just zero? Thanks! THAT was my question.

So, the conclusion is: if point load acts on continuum medium then in finite elements method this situation is modelled as change of nodal forces in JUST ONE node (such that this single node experiences entire load without sharing it with other nodes).

Though is this the only way to model it or are there other approaches?

Comment: If the loading model is realistic or not, it depends on how the actual load is spread or concentrated & how coarse of refined is the mesh. For a coarse mesh and a concentrated load, it can be fine to select only one node.

Answer (score 0):

### Brief answer

In general, every load/forcing has influence on every point of the domain.

### Finite Element Method

It looks like that the main confusion here arises from a poor understanding of Finite Element Methods.

Thus, let's write a brief answer describing the finite element method for a static structural problem of a continuous media.

Let's use here the correspondence:

- continuous $\sim$ infinite-dimensional
- discrete $\sim$ finite-dimensional

### 0 - Fields involved

The fields involved in a problem are:

- $\boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{r})$, displacement
- $\varepsilon \hspace{-3pt} \varepsilon [\boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{r})]$, strain tensor
- $\mathbb{T}[\boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{r})]$, stress tensor, related to the strain tensor by a constitutive equation
- $\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{r})$ volume force density

### 1 - Continuous problem: strong formulation

Assuming small displacement/small strains, the static equilibrium of a continuum, with volume $\Omega$ and boundary $\partial \Omega = \Gamma_D \cup \Gamma_N$, is governed by the differential problem
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  & - \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} = \boldsymbol{f} \ , & & \qquad \boldsymbol{r} \in \Omega \\
  & \boldsymbol{u} = \boldsymbol{u}_b \ , & & \qquad \boldsymbol{r} \in \Gamma_D \\
  & \boldsymbol{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbb{T} = \boldsymbol{t}_n \ , & & \qquad \boldsymbol{r} \in \Gamma_N
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

### 2 - Continuous problem: weak formulation

The weak formulation is derived from the strong formulation,

- multiplying the governing equations for a **test function** (that should have some characteristics that we won't investigate here) $\boldsymbol{w}(\boldsymbol{r})$,
- integrating on the domain $\Omega$
- performing integration by part

to get
\begin{equation}
  \int_{\Omega} \nabla \boldsymbol{w} : \mathbb{T}[\boldsymbol{u}] = \int_{\Omega} \boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{f} + \int_{\Gamma_N} \boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{t}_n
\end{equation}
that should hold for every function $\boldsymbol{w}(\boldsymbol{r})$.

### 3 - Finite-dimensional approximation of continuous fields

Now, a finite-dimensional approximation of the continuous fields are introduced to get a finite-dimensional (usually) linear problem that can be (easily and fast, usually) solved with a computer.

\begin{equation}
  \boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{r}) = \sum_{j=1}^{3N} \boldsymbol{\phi}_j(\boldsymbol{r}) {u}_j  \ , \qquad \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{r}) = \sum_{j=1}^{3N} \boldsymbol{\phi}_j(\boldsymbol{r}) f_j \ , \qquad \dots
\end{equation}

### 4 - Finite-dimensional problem

Inserting the discrete approximation of the fields introduced in 3. into the weak formulation of the problem derived in 2., and using the linearity of the stress tensor in the displacement field $\boldsymbol{u}$ (for linear problems, at least)

\begin{equation}
  \sum_j \left[ \int_{\Omega} \nabla \boldsymbol{w} : \mathbb{T}[\boldsymbol{\phi}_j(\boldsymbol{r})] \right] {u}_j = \sum_j \left[ \int_{\Omega} \boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{\phi}_j \right] f_j + \sum_j \left[ \int_{\Gamma_N} \boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{\phi}_j \right] t_j \ ,
\end{equation}

The last equation contains in general $3 N + 3 N_{\Gamma_D}$ unknowns, assuming a 3-dimensional problem where each point has 3 degrees of freedom (e.g. translation in the 3 Cartesian space directions), being

- $N$ the number of nodes of the volume grid
- $N_{\Gamma_D}$ the number of nodes where displacement is prescribed.

Thus we need $3 N + 3 N_{\Gamma_D}$ equations to solve it.
We get

- $3 N$ linearly independent equations exploiting the arbitrariness of the test function $\boldsymbol{w}$ and choosing $\boldsymbol{\phi}_i$, for $i = 1:3N$, to get
  \begin{equation}
    \sum_j \left[ \int_{\Omega} \nabla \boldsymbol{\phi}_i : \mathbb{T}[\boldsymbol{\phi}_j(\boldsymbol{r})] \right] {u}_j = \sum_j \left[ \int_{\Omega} \boldsymbol{\phi}_i \cdot \boldsymbol{\phi}_j \right] f_j + \sum_j \left[ \int_{\Gamma_N} \boldsymbol{\phi}_i \cdot \boldsymbol{\phi}_j \right] t_j 
  \end{equation}
- $3 N_D$ equations prescribing the nodal displacement
  \begin{equation}
    \boldsymbol{u}_i = \boldsymbol{u}_b (\boldsymbol{r}_i) \ .
  \end{equation}

### 5 - Matrix formulation of the elastic problem and solution by splitting

Collecting the nodal values in two vectors
\begin{equation}
  \underline{U} = [ u_{x,1} , u_{x,2}, \dots , u_{z,N} ]^T \quad , \qquad \underline{U} = [ f_{x,1} , f_{x,2}, \dots , f_{z,N} ]^T
\end{equation}
and splitting these equations in two sets, the ones where displacement is not prescribed $\underline{·}_u$ and the ones where displacement is prescribed $\underline{·}_d$, it's possible to write the problem as

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \begin{bmatrix} \underline{\underline{K}}_{uu} &  \underline{\underline{K}}_{ud} \\ \underline{\underline{K}}_{du} &  \underline{\underline{K}}_{dd} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \underline{U}_{u} \\ \underline{U}_{d} \end{bmatrix}
 =
\begin{bmatrix} \underline{F}_{u} \\ \underline{F}_{d} \end{bmatrix} \\
   & \underline{U}_d = \underline{\bar{U}} \ .
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
In this system of equations, the unknowns are $\underline{U}$ and $\underline{F}_d$. But $\underline{U}_d$ is readily solved by the last equations, so that the actual unknowns are $\underline{U}_u$ and $\underline{F}_d$. It's possible to solve this problem by splitting the first set of equations as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 \underline{\underline{K}}_{uu} \underline{U}_u = F_u - \underline{\underline{K}}_{ud} \underline{F}_d &  \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \underline{U}_u = \dots \\
 & \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \underline{F}_d = \underline{\underline{K}}_{du} \underline{U}_u + \underline{\underline{K}}_{dd} \underline{\bar{U}}_d
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}